# Htaccess remove WWW and Slash + 301 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I can not build a 301 redirect rewrite rule to remove the WWW from the domain name and remove the slashes from the URLs.

*Thank you in advance for your assistance.*

Example:

```
www.domain.com/      to  domain.com
domain.com/          to  domain.com
domain.com/page/     to  domain.com/page
domain.com/page.php  to  domain.com/page
```

My code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$ /$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
#remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R]
#remove .php ext
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Note that this doesn't remove trailing slash from your existing directories. Apache adds a trailing slash when you request an existing dir. If you want to remove this slash then you will need to use the following directive in htaccess

```
DirectorySlash off
```

This tells apache to ignore the slash and you can visit your existing dirs with or without the trailing slash.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

The www and slashes are well delete but cons redirects me to the pages with the visible .php. Is there a way to hide .php extensions?

Comment: I have added a rule for your .php files. Please reload the page to see it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

I will continue to consult the Apache documentation to better understand the use of flags.